# Python pseudocode to code

Tags: python

I am having some problems implementing the code I need to write based on the pseudocode I have.  I would like to code in Python (because I have very limited experience with it), but I have having problems with my "for" statement.

My pseudocode is:

```
PatternCount(Text, Pattern)

    count ← 0

    for i ← 0 to |Text| − |Pattern|

        if Text(i, |Pattern|) = Pattern

        count ← count + 1

    return count
```

with an input of strings Text and Pattern
and I need an output of count(text, pattern)

Comment: I hate problems with your for loop... maybe we could help if you would post whatever python you do have ... (an maybe what those problems are)

Comment: Are you trying to learn something new, or do you want to get work done. If the latter, please use `str.count`: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm

Comment: Incorrect. `str.count()` includes only non-overlapping occurrences  in contrast to the pseudocode.

Answer (score 4):

I think this should work:

```
 text.count(pattern)
```

Comment: Works, of course, but I have a *slight* feeling this is OP's homework and they won't let OP get away with this.

Comment: (actually I have a feeling there are a few edge cases that the pseudo-code  (and by proxy your solution) would return a different count that the teacher might be looking for) (of coarse your solution is not much different (wrt it being hw) since he didnt write that one either)

Comment: Incorrect. `str.count()` includes only non-overlapping occurrences  in contrast to the pseudocode.

Comment: @ArekBulski that was the difference I was refering too in the comment 3 seconds b4 your comment

Comment: @JoranBeasley True, in that case it matters what the task was. I remember having homework that consisted of turning pseudocode into real code, which this looks like to me.

Comment: This answer should not be higher voted than Leviathans since strictly it is not correct.

Comment: @L3viathan Agreed, might be a homework. It does not mean it is a valid and possibly worthy question, so why are people downvoting it...

Comment: @ArekBulski In some sense I think my answer is "more correct" than JoranBeasley's, but I will not remove my upvote, because if it is, OP will keep on reading, and in any case they should know how it should be done in reality.

Comment: (I upvoted your answer @L3viathan... and it will almost certainly be the accepted answer (assuming OP bothers to accept any))

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work:

```
def pattern_count(text, pattern):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(text)-len(pattern)):
        if text[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: ahhh thats what those bars mean :P (+1)

Comment: Cardinality! I think that notation is actually quite common in pseudocode.

Comment: `| -3 |` however makes me think `abs(-3)` .... but yeah i forgot about this symbol for magnitude/cardinality.